# Его императорское величество

Tags: этимология

Почему ранее при упоминании императорской особы говорили, например, "только что изволили прибыть Его императорское величество", а не просто "... изволило прибыть императорское величество", для чего использовалось местоименная форма "его"? Почему если об императоре говорили во множественном числе (изволили), то форма слова "величество" продолжала стоять в единственном числе?

Comment: Изволили – это просторечие. Чехова читали? "Володечка приехали!" – кричала малограмотная нянька. А правильно будет "изволил". Но даже тогдашние малограмотные понимали, что "изволило" об императоре (да и вообще о человеке) сказать нельзя. И множественное число для "величества" тут не употребить. Повторяю, это понимали даже малограмотные.

Comment: Глинка (1946) 54:44

Answer (score 1):

В России был особый протокол титулования в соответствии с Табелью о рангах с употреблением местоимений в так называемом множественном числе величия. Предписывалось обращаться к императору "Ваше Императорское Величество"; "Ваше Императорское Высочество" — к великим князьям (детям и внукам императора, к правнукам и праправнукам императора; Ваше высочество — к князьям императорской крови.

Во втором лице - как обращение на "вы" - множественное число. В третьем лице - соответственно полу фигуранта.  В некоторых случаях к монархам в соответствии с этикетом было применимо только множественное число: "Его императорское величество повелеть изволили". То же относится и к некоторым случаям подобострастной речи слуги о господине: "Их светлость приказали".

Л.Л. Иомдин (Л.Л. Иомдин, Автоматическая обработка текста на естественном языке: модель согласования. М., 1990, стр. 86) пишет:

> "(его) превосходительство/ величество /благородие" ведут себя довольно
>   интересно: а именно, при согласовании с атрибутом как слова среднего
>   рода (в соответствии с морфологией: его императорское величество), но
>   как слова мужского рода (в соответствии с семантикой) при согласовании
>   с глаголом:  Его величество изволил обратить внимание на Артамона
>   Михайловича (Окуджава),
>   но при этом как неодушевленные (вразрез с семантикой): Секретарь
>   уведомил их превосходительства (*их превосходительств), что посол
>   прибудет вечером.

Так что это не "величество" изволил**о** прибыть, а титулованная личность мужского пола - **он изволил**, монарх, но если у Вас есть к нему подобострастное отношение, то **Они**  изволили (как "Вы изволили")